# how to get the value of checked radio button using django and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, radio-button

i have a simple form that includes **text fields** and **radio buttons**
 where the system take the user input  and add new record to the database.

the problem that once the user fill the form and click on **submit button** the system display the below error:

> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   map_person.gender

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    boolChoice = (
        ("M","Male"),("F","Female")
        )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices= boolChoice)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

## addPerson.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="hero__content">
   <form method="POST" class="form-style-9">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}


<ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<li>

    <h2>Add Member</h2>

</li>

<li>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder= "enter ur name " id="name"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="date" name="date" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder= " your birthdate" id="birthdate" />

</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="female"> Female<br>

</li>

<li>
<textarea name="description" class="field-style" placeholder= "introduce yourself " id="description"></textarea>
</li>

<li>
<input type="submit" class="field-style field-full align-none" id="save" value="ADD" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(function(){
                    $('#save').on('click',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        name=$('#name').val()
                        birthdate=$('#birthdate').val()
                        description=$('#description').val()
                        radioValue = $("input[name = 'gender']:checked").val()
                        if (radioValue){
                            alert("radioValue =", radioValue)
                        }
                        alert("name =", name)
                        alert("date =", birthdate)
                        alert("desc =", description)
     $.ajax({
      url:'/addperson/',
      method:'POST',
      data: {

                na:name,
                bi:birthdate,
                de:description,
                ra:radioValue
      },
      headers:{
       'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
      }
     }).done(function(msg) {
                        document.location = "/home.html"
                        alert('ﻟﻘﺪ ﺗﻢّ ﺣﻔﻆ اﻟﻤﻌﻠﻮﻣﺎﺕ')


     }).fail(function(err){
      alert('ﻟﻢ ﻳﺘﻢ اﻟﺤﻔﻆ')
     })
    })
   })
  </script>
</li>
    </ul>
</form>

  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
def addperson(request):
    print("request method = " , request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['na']
        birthdate = request.POST['bi']
        description=request.POST['de']
        radiovalue=request.POST['ra']

        person=Person.objects.create(
            name=name,
            date=birthdate,
            description=description
            )
        person.save()

        return render(request,'./home.html')
    else:
        print("this is a get METHOD")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you're creating the person, you're not setting the gender, so, NOT NULL constraint.

```
person=Person.objects.create(
    name=name,
    date=birthdate,
    description=description,
    # set gender here
)
```

And it's a better practice to split your html files and javascript file.
Semi colon at the end of your lines in javascript is a good practice too.

Is making an ajax call important here? Cause it would be much simpler and proper to use a `django.forms.ModelForm` for what you're doing (as your ajax call redirect on success). 
If you want the page not to refresh when submit, then ajax is the good call.

Comment: ok i added the gender  but now the error is :`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'male' value must be either True or False."]`  in the model i specified the gender as BooleanField

Comment: i see in your choices you have M and F, so in your ```value```, instead of male and female, put M and F.
Or you can do a function in your model. If male then True or False. Well, i don't really see what's a True gender or a False gender

Comment: your choices are not set well. You should avec the True value and the False value in your choices, for your gender field : ```BOOL_CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'))``` for example. Still think booleanfield for gender is a bad idea, for the logic. Just make a normal charfield with two choices possible. It'll be more revelant than having true or false in your datas

Comment: i have changed the boolean to charfield  and now it save all the user input except  the gender.

take a look on the question i will edit the model